# Angularjs ng-change between 1.3x vs 1.6x

Tags: angularjs

I'm upgrading an application from Angularjs 1.3.x to 1.6.x. On a  element there is an ng-change bound to a function call. On this  element there is also a data-element-id attribute that uses an angular expression.

```
<select id="carWashModel" class="form-control w200 " ng-show="currentLocation.CarWashModel.Editable == true" ng-model="currentLocation.CarWashModel.Answer" ng-change="triggerSelectElementUpdate('carWashModel', 'CarWashModel', 'cai')" data-element-id="{{currentLocation.CarWashModel.Id}}" data-element-name="CarWashModel" data-element-description="{{currentLocation.CarWashModel.Question}}">
      <option ng-repeat="opt in currentLocation.CarWashModel.Options" ng-selected="opt==currentLocation.CarWashModel.Answer" value="{{opt}}" label="{{opt}}">{{opt}}</option>
</select>
```

I notice in 1.3.x programmatic changes to the ng-model doesn't raise this ng-change function but in 1.6.x it now does. This causes an issue with the application because inside that change function this programmer uses jquery to get this data-element-id which isn't filled in yet by angular it seems as it's coming back with NaN which causes downstream issues.

What would my options be here to solve this issue? The easy answer would be I don't want ng-change called from programmatically changing the ng-model to get the same older behavior but not sure if that's possible. Is there perhaps a way to tell if it was called from a user change vs program change?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `ng-change` to a `ng-blur` which will trigger the function when the select input has lost its focus.  In that instance it will only happen from the view, but it does have slightly different behavior.